# Отправка данных от php к роботу

Tags: php, html, usb

Интересует такой вопрос. Как управлять с php роботом по usb или com или ...?
Например я собрал usb устройство которое передаёт данные моему роботу. 
Есть страница на локальном сервере с php. Как мне передать значение переменной в php моему устройству?
Может стоит использовать CGI? 
В теме не очень разбираюсь, если кто делал уже такое киньте ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите, может это то что Вы ищите: [PHP Serial Extension](http://www.easyvitools.com/phpserial/index.html)